# Android Auto custom notification sound

Tags: android-auto, android-automotive

I have created a messaging app that support Android Auto and is able to push notifications to it.
My problem is that I can not override the notification sound for my notifications.
I have tried to set sound on Notification Builder and on Notification channel but no luck.
From the documentation, those methods are not forbidden. 
Does anyone has an idea if is possible?

I'm also curies if is possible to force Android Auto to auto read the message without waiting the user to click on play button?

Answer (score 0):

We can add custom sounds in notification channels. But it will mirror sound played on the mobile device. At the moment not possible to add a different sound for car and mobile.

```
  NotificationChannelCompat channel;
    NotificationChannelCompat.Builder channelBuilder = new NotificationChannelCompat.Builder(notificationChannelId,         NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).setName(notificationChanelName);
        channelBuilder.setSound(soundUri, audioBuilder.build()); // Set sound attributes Notification channel
    
    channel = channelBuilder.build();
```